# rgbdslam indigo

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-hydro, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is there any work on rgbdslam ?

It seems that the last version is under fuerte, and not a catkin package.

I've tried to use it under hydro, but I didn't find a way to do it.

Has someone some experience about rgbdslam under hydro ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/165601/rgbdslam-indigo/) by [goupil35000](https://answers.ros.org/users/7096/goupil35000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2014-05-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) on 2014-05-16**:
http://answers.ros.org/question/91111/rgbdslam-in-ros-hydro/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no indigo version. There is a beta release for hydro here: http://felixendres.github.io/rgbdslam_v2/

I am currently too busy to migrate to indigo (and Ubu 14.04), but I am interested to see, whether people here get it to work. For those willing to try, [here's the ROS migration guide](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Migration).

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2014-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0